# Is there any form to group a conditions in a query method with spring-data jpa?

Tags: java, spring, jpa, spring-data, spring-data-jpa

For example, the result sql should be:

```
SELECT * FROM transaction t WHERE t.type = 4 AND (t.status = 1 OR t.value = 2)
```

But in query-method way, I can't figure how it must be

```
public List<Transaction> findByTypeAndStatusAndValue(int type, int status, int value);
```

I am not sure if above code works as I expect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can always provide a custom query:

```
@Query("select t from Transaction t where t.type = ?1 and (t.status = ?2 or t.value = ?3)")
public List<Transaction> findByTypeAndStatusOrValue(int type, int status, int value);
```

Comment: Is it possible to define method instead using `@Query`